# Insufficient privileges to add Azure AD user

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I created a console application to create an Azure AD user as follows (doc referred: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var credential = new ClientCredential("<clientt-id>", "<client-seceret>");
            var authProvider = new HttpRequestMessageAuthenticationProvider(
                                                        credential,
                                                        "https://login.windows.net/<tenant-id>",
                                                        "https://graph.microsoft.com/");

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var user = new User
            {
                AccountEnabled = true,
                DisplayName = "Test User",
                MailNickname = "testuser",
                UserPrincipalName = "testuser@M365xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com ",
                PasswordProfile = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                OnPremisesImmutableId = "id"
            };

            await graphClient.Users
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(user);
        }
```

API permissions added to app are Group.ReadWrite.All and User.ReadWrite.All.

On running this code, I see the following error:

Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

What am I missing?

Comment: Has admin consent been granted to the api permissions?

Comment: Yes granted permissions

Comment: Hi, may I know if your problem was solved ? If still have problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, I summarize the points below which you need to check:

**1.** It seems your code use client_credentials as grant flow to do the job, so please check you have added the permissions of "Application" but not "Delegated". And don't forget grant admin consent.

[image]

**2.** If still show `Authorization_RequestDenied` message, please remove the permission `Group.ReadWrite.All` because this permission is unnecessary. And the `Group` permission may affect other permissions in my past tests.

**3.** It seems you develop the specific code in class `HttpRequestMessageAuthenticationProvider`, actually there is an off-the-shelf SDK avaiable for us to use. I provide my code below for your reference, the code works fine to create a user.

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp23
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create("<client_id>")
                .WithTenantId("<tenant_id>")
                .WithClientSecret("<client_secret>")
                .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var user = new User
            {
                AccountEnabled = true,
                DisplayName = "huryAdd",
                MailNickname = "huryAdd",
                UserPrincipalName = "huryAdd@xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                {
                    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
                    Password = "Password0123"
                },
                OnPremisesImmutableId = "testOnPre"
            };

            await graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(user);

            Console.WriteLine("====success====");
        }
    }
}
```

And also provide the packages installed in my project.

[image]

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Identity.Client -Version 4.16.1
Install-Package Microsoft.Graph
Install-Package Microsoft.Graph.Auth -IncludePrerelease
```

**4.** By the way, there is a blank space in the end of your `UserPrincipalName`. Please remove it, otherwise it will show invalid principal name.

Hope it helps~

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it.

I used the Directory.ReadWrite.All permission but still experienced the problem with setting the OnPremisesImmutableId attribute for our users.

After a bit of investigation, it turned out that i had to assign the roles "Group Administrator" and "User Administrator" to my application in Azure AD Portal (Azure AD > Roles and administrators > Click each group > Add Assignments). After both these roles had been applied to my application, the problem disappeard.